# Is tail recursion optimization guaranteed in Scala when it is possible?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

Suppose I have following code

```
def foo(x:Int):Unit = {
   if (x == 1) println ("done")
   else foo(scala.util.Random.nextInt(10))
}
```

Is it guaranteed that the compiler does tail recursion optimization?

Comment: I don't know what Scala guarantee you, but tail recursion is not implemented in the general case by JVM. (There is no JVM bytecode for tailrec calls)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Scala can compile easy cases of tail recursion to loops. Some JVMs support tail recursion "automatically", but unfortunately Oracle's does not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. To know for sure add the `@tailrec` annotation to your method. This will cause the compiler to throw an error if it does not compile using tail recursion.

```
@tailrec
def foo(x:Int):Unit = {
  if (x == 1) println ("done")
  else foo(scala.util.Random.nextInt(10))
}
```

Comment: In Scala 2.8, I had to do `import scala.annotation.tailrec`.

Comment: Try breaking it. Add an extra () to the bottom of the method so it does something after the call but still returns unit.

Comment: I meant that your suggestion works, I just had to add the import.

Comment: No worries. I got that the first time around. I just meant that you should play with it and see that the compiler does error if you don't have a proper tail recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, the `Unit` return type is irrelevant.

```
scala> @tailrec def f(i: Int) { if (i >= 0) { println(i); f(i - 1) }  }
f: (i: Int)Unit
```

But:

```
scala> @tailrec def f(i: Int) { if (i >= 0) { f(i - 1); println(".") }  }
<console>:11: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method f:
  it contains a recursive call not in tail position
```

You need to have the recursive call as the last call, return type does not matter.

Your code in the question is fine but the title of the question would be misleading.